# Sybase compare columns with duplicate row ids

Tags: comparison, sybase, rows

So far I have a query with a result set (in a temp table) with several columns but I am only concerned with four.  One is a customer ID(varchar), one is Date (smalldatetime), one is Amount(money) and the last is Type(char).  I have multiple rows with the same custmer ID and want to evaluate them based on Date, Amount and Type.  For example:

```
Customer ID     Date          Amount           Type 

   A           1-1-10          200             blue           
   A           1-1-10          400             green           
   A           1-2-10          400             green           
   B           1-11-10         100             blue            
   B           1-11-10         100             red
```

For all occurrences of A I want to compare them to identify only one, first by  earliest date, then by greatest Amount, then if still tied by comparing Types.  I would then return one row for each customer.

I would provide some of the query but I am at home now after spending two days trying to get a correct result.  It looks something like this:

```
(query to populate #tempTable)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING date_cd =
    (SELECT MIN(date_cd)
     FROM order_table ot
     WHERE ot.customerID = #tempTable.customerID
     )
OR date_cd IS NULL
```

I assume the HAVING would result in only one row per customer_id.  This did not end up being the case since there were some ties there.

I am not sure I can do the OR - there are some with NULL values here -  and it did not account for the step to the next comparison if they were all the same anyway.  I am not seeing a way to avoid doing some row processing of the temp table with some kind of IF or WHERE loop.

As I write I am thinking maybe I use #tempTable.date_cd in the HAVING clause instead of looking at the original table.  but that **should** return the same dates?

Am I on the right track or is there something missing?  Suggestions?   More info??

Answer (score 0):

try below query :-

select * from #tempTable
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING isnull(date_cd,"1900/01/01") =min(isnull(date_cd,"1900/01/01"))

Comment: No luck with that one.  In fact, it created 2 ifferent result sets.   It still had multiple rows for the same id

Comment: this could be becuase  there are more than one row with null values.  as u mentioned before  you want  other cluse to add if   more then one records found for one date, you can add  other in and of having clause

Comment: Never mind.  I looked more carefully and it did delete rows with the same id but later dates. Sorry about that.  Now the duplicates that remain have the same dates.  Do you mean some kind of nested HAVING clauses?